Double-digit index is not displayed properly in latex in matplotlib annotation on plot
Double-digit index is not displayed properly in latex in matplotlib annotation on plot
phi = (1 + np.sqrt(5)) / 2
eps = 0.1
a, b = 0, 1

f = lambda x: 2 * x + 1 / x

def _golden_section(eps=0.01, a=0, b=1, f=f) -> tuple[float, int, list[float]]:
    iter_count, steps = 0, []
    #plt.annotate
    while abs(b - a) >= eps:
        x1, x2 = b - (b - a) / phi, a + (b - a) / phi

        if f(x1) >= f(x2):
            a = x1
            steps.append(a)
        else:
            b = x2
            steps.append(b)

        iter_count += 1
    
    return (a + b) / 2, iter_count, steps


###################### plotting ######################

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 4))
h = 0.001

m, _, steps = _golden_section()
# built on f(min), f(max) values
y = [f(m) - h, max(f(0 + h), f(1)) + h]

# add step to 0 because doesn't exist in zero
x = np.arange(0.3 + h, 1 + h, h)

ax[0].plot(x, f(x), label="$f(x) = 2x + \\frac{1}{x}$")
ax[0].plot(m, f(m), "r*")

ax[0].axis('tight')
ax[0].set_xlabel("x")
ax[0].set_ylabel("y")
ax[0].set_title("Golden-Section Search with $\\varepsilon = 0.1$")
ax[0].legend()

Main part:
# vertical line designating steps
for i, l in enumerate(steps, 1):
    ax[0].plot([l, l], y, 'r--', alpha=(len(steps) - i) / len(steps))
    
    ax[0].annotate("$f_{}$".format(i), (l, np.random.uniform(2.8, 3.8)))

And as you can see on graph it doesn't show f_10 properly (Actually you can't see it, because I have less than 10 reputation, but believe me).
I tried it with format like in example and with f-string like this:
ax[0].annotate(f"$f_{i}$", (l, np.random.uniform(2.8, 3.8)))

# or

ax[0].annotate(f"$f_{{i}}$", (l, np.random.uniform(2.8, 3.8)))

but it is the same.
How can I show $f_10$ in annotation?

The suggested duplicate uses .format. You can (and maybe should) use the more modern f-string. In this case: ax[0].annotate(f"$f_{{{i}}}$", (l, np.random.uniform(2.8, 3.8))).

As written in the comments:
ax.annotate(rf'$f_{{{i}}}$')

solves your problem.

No need to write an answer since this is a duplicate question. Just vote it as duplicate.

Okay, thanks for the comment. My answer is just a slight deviation from other suggestions, but still a separate way for solving the problem, which was not mentioned in the question you linked to. Would it be better to add that as a comment when answering duplicate questions in the future?

You can leave this answer since future searchers might find it easier to look at at a glance, but really, duplicates should be closed as such (and once closed as duplicates, the option to post an answer is disabled). And then yes, a comment to explain the minor change would suffice. In some cases, it might not be a minor change, in which case it would no longer be a duplicate.
